# Is magnetic flux real or a mathematical abstraction?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I was looking at an old textbook (The Magnetic Circuit, 1911) that talks about magnetic flux as having a physical manifestation. It says that flux may be an actual flow of an incompressible ether along the lines of force. It says other physicists consider the magnetic circuit to be whirls or vortices in the ether with flux being the momentum of the rotating substance per unit length of the tubes of force.

That's obviously hugely out of date since there's no ether, but it got me wondering if magnetic flux is physically real or if it's just useful mathematics to take the surface integral of the magnetic field. (I hope this question makes sense. I'm not looking for a philosophical discussion of what "real" means.)

Comment: *I'm not looking for a philosophical discussion of what "real" means.* You ask whether something is “physically real” but don’t want to explain what that means to you?

Comment: I think your question actually is a philosophical discussion of what real means. The only difference between something like magnetic or electric field or flux and something like pressure or force gradient or flux is that you can detect those directly with your senses and you are so used to it you just don't question it.

Comment: Why are you asking about the reality of the field’s flux rather than about the reality of the field *itself*?

Comment: For example, a balloon: you can represent the pressure inside with a field. Is the sum of the pressure vectors at the surface of the balloon real? Or the sum of the pressure vector over an small area of the balloon. I don't think you would have any doubt saying it is since it's the total outward force exerted by the balloon, because you can directly touch it.

Comment: To put G. Smith's question a little differently: would you accept magnetic flux is real if the reality of the magnetic field could be demonstrated to your satisfaction?

Comment: Would it satisfy you (without going too deep down the philosopical rabbit hole) if we pointed out a physical quantity that is useful to describe the world, and that can be interpreted as "the thing that flows"?

If that's what you're after, then the answer to the question is "no". There is no quantity that is physically meaningful in other contexts, which satisfies a continuity equation together with the magnetic field.

Comment: @Quantumwhisp Yes, that answer would satisfy me. Essentially, I want to a) know if there's something (like electrons in a wire) that is actually flowing, and b) what's the right "mindset" for thinking about flux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the word “real” is a philosophical concept (part of the philosophical discipline of metaphysics). You really cannot avoid philosophy if you use the word. I avoid the word “real” for that reason and recommend others avoid it in a scientific discussion also. It is preferable to say what you mean explicitly.

For example, some scientifically minded people mean “can it be experimentally measured?” If you are one then magnetic flux is real.

Others may mean “is it frame invariant?” If you are one of those then magnetic flux is not real.

If you mean something else then you will need to be specific.

Comment: "Others may mean “is it frame invariant?” If you are one of those then magnetic flux is real." Do you mean *not* real?

Comment: Oops. Yes. I have fixed it, thank you